# Finding similar curves with given tangent

Tags: curves, tangent-line

Good evening.

There are different parabolic curves which have the same equation for the same value in parameter.

For example. For $n = 2$:

$$299 = 4n^2 + 44n + 195 $$

and,

$$299 = 4n^2 + 56n + 171$$

the line which intersects these parabolic curves at point $(2,299)$ has a equation of $2n+295$.

I can calculate the tangent between these curves by:

$(195 - 171) / (44 - 56) = -2 $; which is the negative value for the $2n+295$, I mean here the tangent is $2$.

My question is the following one: How can I auto-generate different parabolic curves when I have the desired tangent, like the $-2$ above described ?

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ to write math equations in future. [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) the basic tutorial.

Comment: I found another way to get the curves. Thanks for contributing.